# Linq to join two tables using a value to where clause dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, sql-server-2008, controller

These are my [tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Kpj.png)

I want an output where the `U_CCode` of first table, which is also a foreign key to my second table can be used to join both to show something like this (note : here I have passed `A1` as parameter to where clause but I want it to dynamically select whatever value of `U_CCode` I assign to the controller by a string variable. I want to achieve this using `LINQ` and I am not able to understand how to use it in MVC controller.

I want to assign the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTFX1.png) of this query to a `selectlist` which I want to use in my view via `viewbag`.

I am new to this, can someone help me with the script for this query?

**CODE**

```
public ActionResult Create(string U_CCode)
{
    var departments = db.Class.Where(q => q.U_CCode == U_CCode); 
    ViewBag.SelectedDepartment = new SelectList(departments, "U_CLCode", "U_CLName");
}
```

Comment: Can you please show your existing implementation ?

Comment: @SamGhatak var departments = db.Class.Where(q => q.U_CCode == U_CCode);  
            ViewBag.SelectedDepartment = new SelectList(departments, "U_CLCode", "U_CLName");   // here Class is dbset of my second table.

Comment: @gypsyCoder  public ActionResult Create(string U_CCode){ var departments = db.Class.Where(q => q.U_CCode == U_CCode);  
            ViewBag.SelectedDepartment = new SelectList(departments, "U_CLCode", "U_CLName");}

Comment: So whats the exact problem with that

Comment: @VarunVasishtha The linq query doesn't work. It throws null value.

Comment: you are matching "U_CCode" and you are taking it in string.. is it string in table?

Comment: @VarunVasishtha yes it is.

Comment: I am not sure...is it anyway related to the lazy operations??? in that case add a `.First()` at the end of linq

Comment: @SamGhatak I tried doing this : 'var departmentsQuery = (from e in db.Class
                                   where e.U_CCode==U_CCode 
                                   select e).ToList();' Now it seems to be working. However, how can I assign this list to a viewbag. Also I want to access this viewbag as a dropdown in my view and it's not binded to any element in my model, so how to call through '@Html.DropDownList' instead of '@Html.DropDownListFor'?

Comment: You can pass it as a selectlist...just like you planned earlier...selectlist has a constructor with a IEnumerable and object..

Comment: Please add everything that's relevant to the question text itself, so we don't have to piece it together from links or comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:**(EDITED)**

```
var departmentsQuery = (from e in db.Class where e.U_CCode==U_CCode select e).ToList();
ViewBag.SelectedDepartment = departmentsQuery;
```

Pass it to the view..

In view:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "name", 
    new SelectList(
        ((List<yourTypename>)ViewBag.SelectedDepartment).Select(x => new { Value = x.U_CCode, Text = x.U_CLName }),
        "Value",
        "Text"
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I don't have this field in my model and I can't add it because except for this all other fields I have in the model are to be added it in a dynamic table hence will be using a list type of viewmodel (excluding this dropdown field). I just want the output list of the linq query to be displayed in a dropdown so I would be passing the result as a string parameter in the beginform line and the model (which is a grid like dynamic table in my view).

Comment: So simply extract it out from the viewbag...let me edit it, might be helpful

Comment: Accept the answer if helpful. it helps future users too...cheers :)